# How to format properly 'X-Cf-App-Instance'?

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

Has someone tried to specify explicitly what instance of an application on CF should receive a request? I try to add a special header in form of 'X-Cf-App-Instance': '19eb77aa-4bbc-4e01-47a7-faac:1'  where 19eb77aa-4bbc-4e01-47a7-faac  is taken from CF_INSTANCE_GUID  environment variable of a target application and 1  is taken from CF_INSTANCE_ID  env variable of a target application. I get 400 Bad request  response with 'x-cf-routererror': 'invalid_cf_app_instance_header'  in headers meaning that
"The value provided for X-Cf-App-Instance includes an incorrectly formatted app GUID."